# SignalR WinForms SelfHost

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I'm trying to use a WinForms application with SignalR Self-Host, but it doesnt work. I have the following code:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

    #if DEBUG
            app.UseErrorPage();
    #endif
            app.UseWelcomePage("/");
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
    using (WebApp.Start("http://192.168.0.25:10888"))
    {
        // Success notification                
    }
```

After launching of my application it shows that server started successfully but when i try to navigate to http://192.168.0.25:10888 using a web browser i see a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" message.

Absolutely the same code (copy/paste) works great in console application, but not in WinForms (the same port is used and the same NuGet packages installed). It looks like that WinForms version doesnt even start a server because it doesnt throw an exception when i try to launch it without administrator permissions while console version fails.

I've tried to place SignalR initialization code in form constructor and Main() functions but still no results.

Comment: Is your firewall on? Does it work on localhost? Does it work if you run the server as administrator?

Comment: @Brannon - firewall is disabled. As i wrote console version works great on the same port. No, it doesnt work when i start it as administrator.